# Escape $ dollar sign in variable and execution of command

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
startCmnd="sudo -- bash -c"
test="${startCmnd} \"echo 'Hello this is a \$TEST' >> hello.txt\""
bash -c "${test}"
```

The expected result must be the text `Hello this is a $TEST` inside the file, but instead of that, it only put `Hello this is a`.

It has to be done in that way

Does anyone has any idea of how I fix this or a better way to accomplish this?

Any help it would be preciated

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946

Comment: Please explain "_isn't working_". You've told us what you expected, which is good. But what happened instead?

Comment: @Kusalananda not sure about that dupe here

Comment: @roaima In as much as it's about running a command in a variable.  Did not mark it as a dupe though as someone may want to also remove the three levels of child shells that the code is using.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the advice, I have updated the question

Comment: This seems to be a quoting issue. I'm guessing it would work with `\\\$TEST`.

Comment: @Kusalananda It works, thanks! I think since I have 2 "quotation" levels I have to escape the escaping character that escapes the $ dollar sign